# Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:4000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I looked around and can't figure this error out.

While running a spec I get this error right where the binding pry is `Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3000`. Any ideas on how to fix it?

When I run the development rails server the error goes away and the code runs.

```
    10: def call
 => 11:   binding.pry
    12:   image = MiniMagick::Image.open(url)
    13: end

[1] pry(#<ResizeImage>)> image = MiniMagick::Image.open(url)
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3000 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3000)
from /Users/josephkonop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:939:in `rescue in block in connect'
```

Here is the code

```
class ResizeImage
  attr_reader :url, :width, :height

  def initialize(params)
    @url = params[:url]
    @width = params[:width]
    @height = params[:height]
  end

  def call
    binding.pry
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(url)
  end
end

The spec:

RSpec.describe 'Image Resizer', type: :request do
  describe '#create' do
    context 'when valid params' do
      let(:image_url) { ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("cat.jpg") }
      let(:width) { 300 }
      let(:height) { 200 }

      before do
        post "/api/v1/resize?url=#{image_url}&width=#{width}&height=#{height}"
      end

      it 'response' do
        expect(response.body).to eq('')
      end
    end
  end
end

Test.rb

config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

Comment: Have you tried using `asset_url` instead of `asset_path`?

Comment: @max Thanks for your reply. I just tried that. Same error.

Comment: what's running on port 4000?

Comment: @emaillenin Hey its now port 3000. I get the same error. In the code above i added test.rb. It shows my asset_host is 'http://localhost:3000'. Its required so `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("cat.jpg")` has a host url. Otherwise it will just be /cat.jpg.

Comment: I also ran the test server `rails s -e test` and it works. I think it's trying to make a http request to get the image. Maybe the implementation is wrong. But if someone knows how to get this code to work without mocking it that would be awesome.